# When checking out a jenkinsfile from a Github repo, can the jenkinsfile call/start a python script from that same Repo?

Tags: python, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am starting a Jenkins pipeline script from SCM and Jenkins is able to read the jenkinsfile but cannot find the rest of the files in that repo.  Does this need to be done in a differnt way, or even possible?

Github repo:

```
-jenkinsfile
-python_scripts/generate_json.py
```

```
node ('windows7') {
    stage('Generate json file'){
        bat 'dir'
        bat 'dir ..'
        bat 'python ./python_scripts/generate_json.py'
    }
}
```

It is unable to locate the python script:

```
J:\Jenkins_Slave\workspace\[redacted]\test_pipeline>python ./python_scripts/generate_json.py 
python: can't open file './python_scripts/generate_json.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have also disabled lightweight checkout but it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is your entire pipeline, you're missing the step to checkout your source code actually:

```
node ('windows7') {
    stage('Generate json file'){
        checkout scm
        bat 'dir'
        bat 'dir ..'
        bat 'python ./python_scripts/generate_json.py'
    }
}
```

Actually, I guess that's what the `dir` calls should already have shown you, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a step to checkout your sources on the node you are running your build on. Initial checkout to read Jenkinsfile is on the master, if you switch to a different node, no files are in that workspace.
Add this inside your `node`-Block.

```groovy
    stage('Checkout sources') {
        checkout scm // Checks out the repo where the Jenkinsfile is located
    }
```

To expand on it: When a jenkins pipeline reads a Jenkinsfile, it checks it out on the jenkins master first, evaluate what to do and where, i.e. it will read the `node('Windows7')` and try to get a free executor on a node with label `Windows7`. It will then switch execution to run on that node.

In your case it checks out your git repo, and switch to the windows node with an empty workspace since the initial checkout was on the master. This is only done to read the Jenkinsfile, so keep lightweight checked, its uses less ressources.